# In a form, how to find out which option is selected when it has two select?_ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Recently I use Jquery and for days I can't solve this: I have one form with two select, like this:

```
<form action="#">

<fieldset>
    <h3>Colors</h3>
    <select name="colors" class="colors">
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <select name="fruits" class="fruits">
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="pear">Pear</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

And I need to know which option is selected to be shown after. When a form has only one select I can do that, but in this case (more than one) I don´t know.

Someone who can help me please? I hope I've explained that clearly, my English is poor.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
<form action="#">

<fieldset>
    <h3>Colors</h3>
    <select name="colors" class="colors">
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    </select>
    <div id="colordiv"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <select name="fruits" class="fruits">
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="pear">Pear</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <div id="fruitsdiv"></div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

And jquery code would be:

```
//when page loads
$(document).ready(function(){
    //event handler on change for class colors
    $(".colors").change(function(){
        //get selected value
        var slectedvar=$(this).val();
        //set the div content to show what we selected
        $("#colordiv").html("Selected value: "+slectedvar);
    });
    //event handler on change for class fruits
    $(".fruits").change(function(){
        //get selected value
        var slectedvar=$(this).val();
        //set the div content to show what we selected
        $("#fruitsdiv").html("Selected value: "+slectedvar);
    });    
});
```

Here, go fiddle with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nesha8x8/ns8jF/

Comment: @Nesha8x8, I applaud you. While we (Jeff & I) sat around explaining, you came & gave an actual solution, and linked to a place he could actually use it. Probably took you less time than our explaining, as well. Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
$("select#id").filter(":selected").val();
```

So in your case if you want the `fruits` selected val, it would be      `$("select#fruits").filter(":selected").val();`

If you wanted the colors, it would be 
`$("select#colors").filter(":selected").val();`

Comment: I agree with you. But the problem is I need to know which option is selected in either, select either within the form.

Comment: I don't know if I explained well. Thanks

Comment: What Jeff said should be correct. The `$("select#fruits")` part gets anything inside the `<select>` tag with id `fruits`, while the filter calls anything that is selected (options, radio buttons, etc.) Put them together & you should get the option the user selected under the `fruits` `select` tag. To do the same thing for the `colors` `select` tag, replace `fruits` with `colors`. If my explanation was too long or confusing I can clarify.

Comment: Sorry... I have several forms with more than one select each, are part of an online store. The form one is called 'Products' and has one select (their options are cake, cupcake, cookie,...) and each product has another select associated called 'Bases' (their options are lemon, orange,... depending on the product chosen in the previous form) all them within another form. The option chosen in the first form is shown later in a div (for example) and the option chosen in the second form is shown in another div.

Comment: With many select inside a form I don't know how to find out which option I've been selected (only of one select, the rest of select to be associated with 'Products' unselected, not taken into account)

Comment: As I said in my previous answer, you may just want to use AJAX.

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of selects that are not used, you could just have one set of selects and populate them based on what is selected. For example, have a Product select and Bases select. If product "cupcake" is selected, then populate the Bases with the cupcake bases. If "cake" is selected, then populate the Bases with cake bases. This could all be done with jquery.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. All the answers so far only get data from a single `<select>` tag, and in fact a single `<option>` value from that single `<select>` tag. I'm not sure how much more specific you want to get.

Comment: Yes, when I select a Product within a form One the select associated to this within a form Two is shown (the image), but I need to get the value to display it in a final summary (like a shopping cart). Thans a lot and sorry the disturb

Comment: Did you have an image here? It is not showing in your comment.

Comment: What do you have so far for jQuery related to this question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought It would be more confused

Comment: No, we can read jQuery. If anything, we could have puzzled it out. Nevermind, though, because @Nesha8x8 The Great saved you.

Comment: At present I will try the Nesha8x8's solution, but I couldnt have done it without you (Jeff, Trysis and Nesha8x8). Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a `select` tag, use PHP's `$_POST` variable when the user submits the form. To get a `select` with the name `fruits` call `$_POST["fruits"]`, and to get the value of the `colors` `select` tag call `$_POST["colors"]`.

For your code these would be on the page you sent the form to, which would be the page on the URL in the `action` attribute in your `form` tag. As the page you redirect to is the same page, this would be harder, but there are ways to do it. You might be better off using AJAX.